# How to transfer files from Windows to Ubuntu on Virtualbox?

Tags: ubuntu, files, windows, virtualbox

How should I transfer files from Windows to Ubuntu installed on Virtualbox? When I plugged in a USB, it only pops up in Windows.

How can I see it in Ubuntu?

Comment: I would love to do the opposite

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are 2 ways, which I normally use

Option 1: 
Before booting up Ubuntu, inside Virtualbox Ubuntu VM settings, specify a share folder. Then after logged in to Ubuntu, create a new directory for example `/media/vboxshared` and mount that drive using the command `sudo mount -t vboxsf SHARENAME /media/vboxshared`. Enter your password when it prompts for the password.

Option 2: 
Before booting up Ubuntu, add a new Network adapter and select 'Bridged Adapter'. Then after logged in to Ubuntu, run the command `ifconfig -a | more` to get the ip address of that new network adapter. In Windows, use WinSCP or FileZilla to transfer the file to Ubuntu

Comment: **Option 1** is **not working** for me! I get `/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device`

Answer (score 34):

Thank you for Alvin Sim's answer. Though it is clear, I still spend some time to do everything correct. OK, here are my detailed steps using Alvin Sim's Option 1.

1. Before starting your Guest
2. Go to VirtualBox Manager
3. Select your interested Guest
4. Go to Guest *Settings*
5. In Guest *Settings*, scroll the left side-menu, and go to *Shared Folders*
6. In *Shared Folders*, add your interested folder in the Host machine
7. After adding your Host folder path, you will see an updated *Folders List* in *Shared Folders*. Remember your newly folder *Name* shown in this list. Say it is `HOST_SHARE`.
8. Click OK and save your changes.
9. Start your Guest machine
10. In Guest machine, create a new folder, e.g. `GUEST_SHARE`
11. In Guest terminal, type

    ```
    sudo mount -t vboxsf HOST_SHARE GUEST_SHARE`
    ```

    If you see the error `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on …`, this means you first need to install `virtualbox-guest-utils`.

    ```
    sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
    ```

    Then run the `mount` command again
12. You shall find your stuffs in this `GUEST_SHARE` folder.

Comment: Still works as of Ubuntu 16.04, Windows 10, and VirtualBox 5.1.14

Comment: Thank you so much for the "wrong fs type" error mention; I kept getting this error no matter which guide I was following and was puzzled, but got everything working after this "apt-get". I am surprised this utility package is not mentioned anywhere else. It wasn't obvious for a newer user like me.

Comment: Thank you! I found many other similar answers, but nobody else thought to mention the part about installing `virtualbox-guest-utils`

Comment: Was encountering an error, fixed by making sure GUEST_SHARE and HOST_SHARE had different names

Comment: Thanks you. After install `virtualbox-guest-utils` package everything works fine.

Comment: +1 to use different names!!

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf SHARENAME /media/vboxshared
```

1. create your shared folder at your PC. for example "c:\SharedBoth"
2. make sure you have selected your shared folder `c:\SharedBoth` at virtualbox menu "settings"  - "shared folders" - "add" -"permanent/automount", before you start the ubuntu virtual machine.
3. start the ubuntu terminal, type in command above,
   `sudo mount -t vboxsf SharedBoth /media`
4. then check if folder sf_SharedBoth created in media folder
   Before you do the step 3, you need to make sure you have installed "guest additions"

Answer (score 3):

In any case, you can easily make the USB key visible in the guest.  From your question I imagine you run Ubuntu in a guest and the host is Windows.

Whenever you insert an USB key, if you want to see it in the guest proceed as follows:

1. Cleanly unmount the USB from windows by clicking on the corresponding icon in the bottom right corner and selecting the "safely remove ..." option.
2. In your VirtualBox window select the "Devices => usb devices" menu item on the top left guest window menu and select your USB key.  It should appear in Ubuntu now.

This operation is equivalent to physically inserting your USB key in a USB port of your guest machine.

Otherwise, the other options are

1. Shared folder as stated in laebshade's and Alvin Sim's answers.  But that can be slow.
2. FTP etc... as also stated in Alvin Sim"s answer (assumes you have an ftp server on your Windows host).
3. A simple samba mount from the guest:

   ```
   mount -t cifs //winhost/share /home/yourname/mntpoint -o user=winusr%paswd,uid=0,gid=0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
   ```
4. For small volumes and frequent synchronisation, open a dropbox account.

Answer (score 3):

1. In virtual box, login to Ubuntu.
2. In menu bar click devices -> USB devices -> Select your device (Pendrive).
3. Then go to the Home folder. On the left you'll see your device.

Answer (score 2):

Which is the host, and which is the guest?  Either way, Virtualbox has a sharing mechanism you can use; just install the Guest Additions [as described in the documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) then setup a share in the VirtualBox configuration.

Comment: I went through that but when I tried to mount that I got an 'only root can do that' error.

Comment: @laebshade: The OP already stated which way around this was in his question. Windows is the host, Ubuntu is the guest.